# Can i charge an LiFePo4 32650 cell using an 18650 li-ion charger

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion, charger, lithium-polymer

i have this li-ion 18650 charger i found, pic attached below. I need to know if i can use this to charge a LiFePo4 32650 cell i bought [here](https://robokits.co.in/batteries-chargers/lifepo4-battery/3.2v-lifepo4-battery-2.8v-3.7v/high-quality-lifepo4-32650-rechargeable-cell-3.2v-6000mah-with-3000-charge-cycles), the cell doesnt fit in due to the obvious differences in size, but apart from that could i use it to charge my lifepo4 cell by just hooking up the terminals, or would the battery be damaged in any way, any help would be highly useful. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: What is the charging voltage & current needed for your 32650 cell? Does the charger you show match that? If it does not, then the answer is: **no**.

Comment: @SolarMike the website mentions the following- Charging Cut-off voltage:3.7V, Max.Charging Current(Continue):1C, Charging Methods Standard: 0.2C*6.5Hrs. Since the charger output is 4.2v does it mean its not compatible with my battery?

Comment: What does "Charging Cut-off voltage:3.7V" mean? what does the battery require? Match the information.

Comment: No, the chemistry and thus the charging voltage profile are different. This will not work. Get a LiFePO4 charger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No it will not. Trying to do so will damage your battery** - as it is a LiFePO4 chemistry, it might not burn down your house, but still, overcharging batteries is dangerous.

Your charger has a 4.2 V maximum charge voltage and 650 mA charge current.

Your website actually tells you what you need to know for charging the battery:

- Cutoff voltage (at which voltage must the charging stop): 3.7 V
- Maximum charge current: 1C (which is not Coulomb but indicates it can be charged at 1 times the capacity rating, so for a 6000 mAh battery like this it means 6000 mA maximum charge current

If you want to know if charging works you have to stay below the limits of the battery. So it will fail because it will charge to 4.2 V instead of only 3.7 V.